# Laravel - FatalThrowableError Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel so I'm not familiar with errors in the framework .I'm trying to get the user to make a post but I'm getting the above error .Could you please tell where I'm going wrong ?Thank you

This is my HomeController class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $r)
    {
        if(Input::has('status-text'))
        {
            $text = e(Input::get('status-text'));
            $userStatus = new Status();
            $userStatus->status_text = $text;
            $userStatus->save();
            Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
            return redirect(route('home'));

                }


        return view('home');
    }
}
```

And this is my web.php class :

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::any('/home', ['as'=> 'home','uses' =>'HomeController@index']);
```

Comment: add `use Input;` top of controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Input::get()`, use `$r->get()` as you're injecting the request as a dependency to the `index` method already, and `Input::` is merely a alias to access the underlaying `Request`.

Comment: I changed it to  `$text = e($request->get('status-text'));` and still got the same error message

Comment: @Russkiy You aliased `$request` as `$r`...so use `$r->get` not `$request->get`

Comment: That didn't help too :/

Comment: @Russkiy How did you import `Request`? `use Illuminate\Http\Request`?

Comment: It didn't work because OP used `$r` when referencing `Request` instead of `$request`

Comment: @Derek It is not a requirement of the `Request` to be aliased as as `$request`. It can be any variable you want.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy my apologies, you edited your answer and my display didn't show. I know it isn't required, I saw your initial answer ($request instead of what OP used).

Comment: @Derek No worries!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Fixed it ,I just added `use Request;` at the top of the class